# Symfony Placeholder in twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a username in my table

```
1. username
```

I want to insert placeholder with font awesome :

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': '&#xf040; your username', 'style':'font-family:Arial, FontAwesome' } }) }}
```

**But it is not working.**
[image]

Comment: How it is not working? Is there an error/exception, or something wrong is displayed, or nothing is displayed? Give more details.

Comment: @Stepashka, look my comment

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony [pipes the placeholder](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L354) attribute through the [trans filter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-filters) which causes your placeholder to be escaped for HTML output, so that it is rendered as-is and not interpreted as HTML code. In your case, it is replacing the `&` with `&amp;`, so that it is rendered directly as an `&`.

Use the character U+F040 directly instead of the HTML entity. You can copy and paste it from here:

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': ' your username', 'style':'font-family:Arial, FontAwesome' } }) }}
```

If the encoding you're saving your files as doesn't support that you will need to use a custom or overridden form_widget so that the placeholder is piped through the raw filter.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 7, you can now easily insert unicode using double-quotes : `"\u{F040}"`

```
{{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control','placeholder': "\u{F040}".' your username', 'style':'font-family:Arial, FontAwesome' } })
```